# IIterating a list to show duplicates and the deltas of those duplicates

Tags: pandas, list, data-analysis

Learning python and pandas, not sure I still have the gray matter for this task but I find python programming to be fascinating. Wish I had started 60 years ago. The task I'm trying to accomplish is this. I have a list of random repeating numbers. What I want is first to count the duplicates and then find the deltas of the duplicates. This is a basic layout of my objective.

```
1                    numbers    total    first-occurence   Delta_1
9                      0          2            5             4
1                      1          2            1             2
3                      2          1            9
0                      3          3            4             2
3                      4          0
6                      5          0
0                      6
2                      7
0                      8
                       9
```

The analysis would be the columns to the right and I want it to be a dataframe with 9 rows and as many columns as there are duplicates. I have found many ways to come up with the duplicate count which is not a problem but to determine what the deltas are and to populate the dataframe columns is. I hope I have explained my objective clearly enough so that any kind soul that might be willing to help is not confused.

No idea where to start on delta frequency. Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach to problem, You should try breaking down your problem into smaller solvable chunks to understand it better.

A good starting point to solving this is as below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

random_nums = np.array([1, 9, 1, 3, 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 0])

df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": range(min(random_nums), max(random_nums) + 1)})

df["total"] = df["numbers"].map(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(random_nums == x))

df["first_occurrence"] = df["numbers"].map(lambda x: np.argmax(random_nums == x))

df["delta"] = np.nan

# Delta only makes sense if the number of duplicates are atleast 2
df.loc[df.total >= 2, "delta"] = df.loc[df.total >= 2, "numbers"].map(
    lambda x: np.ptp(np.where(random_nums == x))  # Peak to peak difference of indices
)

print(df)
```

Output

```
   numbers  total  first_occurrence  delta
0        0      3                 4    5.0
1        1      2                 0    2.0
2        2      1                 8    NaN
3        3      2                 3    2.0
4        4      0                 0    NaN
5        5      0                 0    NaN
6        6      1                 6    NaN
7        7      0                 0    NaN
8        8      0                 0    NaN
9        9      1                 1    NaN
```